# small width of <select> tag but large window for select2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2-4

I am looking for a way to code my selects which have a small width so that once they are clicked the window that opens will have a certain dimension that is definitely larger than the one I have already. For instance if I have

```
<select id = "tester" style = "width:20px">
```

then with the familiar `$("#tester").select2();`

(which is relatively small), when the user clicks on the select (which in my case has options that are about 6-8 words long) the window that shows is much too small to read anything. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Forgot your example by any chance?

Comment: @Dekel will add oops!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select2 - Setting different width to input and dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519233/select2-setting-different-width-to-input-and-dropdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrapp your `<select>` tag

like this:

```
<div style="width: 20px">
   <select id="tester">
</div>
```

It should work fine. 
Also you can add `max-width: 20px` to the div